# Adding stopwatch and clicking objects that will make other ones disappear in jquery

Tags: rotation, jquery-animate, stopwatch

I am making a little game for my website.
I will have a bunch of colourful circles that change colour when you hover but when you click each will disappear.
I have two questions.
1) How can I make some random circle disappear when I press a certain one (I mean I don't wanna to get rid of the one I clicked but instead some other random. Just to train coordination).
2) How can I add timer that will start the moment you click the first item and the moment you click the last one?

and here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?3.35.2"></script>
<script>jsbinShowEdit && jsbinShowEdit({"static":"http://static.jsbin.com","root":"http://jsbin.com"});</script>
    <title> game no 5 </title>


<style>
.container{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:40%;
    width:100px;
}
.one{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:pink;

    position: absolute;
}
.two{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:pink;

    position: absolute;
    left:100px;
}
.three{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:pink;

    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
}
.four{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:pink;

    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
}
.five{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
.six{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:pink;

    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
}




</style>


        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="one pop"></div>
        <div class="two pop"></div>
        <div class="three pop"></div>
        <div class="four pop"></div>
        <div class="five pop"></div>
        <div class="six pop"></div>
    </div>


<script>



var safeColors = ['00','33','66','99','cc','ff'];

    var rand = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    };

        var randomColor = function() {
            var r = safeColors[rand()];
            var g = safeColors[rand()];
            var b = safeColors[rand()];
            return "#"+r+g+b;
        };

            $('.pop').hover(function() {
                $('div').each(function() {
                    $(this).css('background',randomColor());

                });
            });

                $(".pop").click(function(){
                    $(this).toggle();
                });

</script>

    </body>

</html>
```